# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

error code

```
bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = globalFormKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:thex/components/account_check.dart';
import 'package:thex/components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:thex/components/rounded_input_field.dart';
import 'package:thex/components/rounded_password_field.dart';
import 'package:thex/constants.dart';
import 'package:thex/models/login_model.dart';
import 'package:thex/screen/Login/components/background.dart';
// import 'package:thex/screen/home/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:thex/screen/signup/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';


class Body extends StatelessWidget {
   Body({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  LoginRequestModel? requestModel;

  void initState() {
    requestModel = LoginRequestModel();
  }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Background(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: size.height * 0.04),
            child: const Text(
              "Sign In", 
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 34, color: kPrimaryColor),
            ),
          ),
          SvgPicture.asset(
            "assets/icons/login.svg", 
            height: size.height * 0.35
          ),
          RoundedInputField(
            validator: (value) => ! value!.contains('@') ? null : 'Invalid Email',
            hintText: "Your Email",
            onSaved: (value) {
              requestModel!.email = value;
            },
          ),
          RoundedPasswordField(
            validator: (password) =>  password!.length < 6 ? 'Password too short' : null,
            hintText: "Your Password",
            onSaved: (password) {
              requestModel!.password = password;
            },
          ),
          RoundedButton(
            text: "LOGIN",
            press: () {
              if (validateAndSave()) {
                print(requestModel!.toJson());
              }
              // Navigator.push(
              //   context,
              //   MaterialPageRoute(
              //     builder: (context) {
              //       return const HomeScreen();
              //     },
              //   ),
              // );
            
            },
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              AlreadyHaveAnAccountCheck(
                press: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context, 
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context){
                        return const SignUpScreen();
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text("Don't have an account? ", style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () { launch("https://www.web.com/forgot-password");},
                child: const Text("Reset Password", style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }  

  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = globalFormKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

help!!

Comment: Which line of code throws the error?

Comment: if (form.validate()) {

Comment: Are you sure it's that line? There is no null check operator there.

Comment: You didn't use `globalFormKey` as key in a `Form` but you are using `.validate()`. Maybe that's why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is you dont have a form element in your widget. There for its null.

You need to add a Form widget with the key.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Background(
      child: Form(
         key: globalFormKey,
         child: Column(
            ...
         )
      )
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use "!" to force not null. Instead, use
`?? defaultValue` or check null before use "!".
Also, use debugging mode (f5) to check flow and know where code die.